# Error: vgubuntu-root does not exist. Dropping to a shell

Tags: boot, encryption, lvm, luks, 21.04

I installed Ubuntu 21.04 with disk encryption a week ago. Now it won't boot and gives this error message:

```
ALERT! /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to get into the laptop. Here's what I did:

On the initramfs screen I typed (replace nvme0n1p3 with your Luks partition):

> cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p3 tmpData

Cryptsetup then asked my passphrase which I typed.

After that I simply exited initramfs:

> exit

And ta-da! It booted normally.

When I reboot the laptop the error persists though so I still have to figure out how to fix that. I will probably have to mess with some or all of these files:

```
/etc/fstab
/etc/crypttab
/boot/grub/grub.conf
```

If anyone knows what to do please share!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (see [22.04 (LVM, encrypted) stopped booting, drop to shell: Error: vgubuntu-root does not exist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1454424/22-04-lvm-encrypted-stopped-booting-drop-to-shell-error-vgubuntu-root-does?noredirect=1#comment2544421_1454424)) which turned out to be a mismatch between the physical location of the encrypted partition and how it's labeled in /etc/crypttab.  Editing the file to correct that solved the boot problem:

Partition is sda3, but /etc/crypttab entry was for sda6_crypt; edited to sda3_crypt and regenerate initramfs:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```